# How can we transfer an outbound Twilio voice call to another number without dropping?

Tags: twilio

- A makes outbound call to B
- A wants to transfer the call to C without dropping B
- A then wants to hang up leaving B and C on the call

I have read all similar questions here on SO.  The developer evangelist has said to use conference calls from the start or look for and modify the child leg of a call.

Conference calls:

- A creates conference (and joins it implicitly)
- A dials B with webhook that responds with instructions to join same conference
- A and B are in the conference
- A wants to add C which is defined by TwiML at a URL -- not supported
- A wants to hang up at this point leaving B and C on the conference call

Modifying the child leg doesn't work as it seems (as of at least June 2021) that there is no call sid created for the receiving party ("B" here) of a direct call.  Modifying the direct call with new TwiML for instance changes the instructions for the caller ("A" here), dropping the receiving party (B) from the call.

Is there a way to accomplish A calls B then A transfers B to C without dropping B and then A hangs up (not dropping B or C)?

Comment: Hey Brian, not sure what isn't supported about adding C to the conference call. Can you explain that further please?

Comment: C isn't a phone number to call but new TwiML/instructions for B. I don't think that is supported. I don't see how to do it via a direct call as well -- that is, A calls B but A wants to give new instructions to B by updating the call with new TwiML

Comment: OK, I think you're saying that the main issue is not being able to get the Call Sid for B. But I am not sure why you are trying to invoke TwiML on B in order to have a 3rd caller join. Can you use the [conference participant API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource) to create a new call to your 3rd caller that adds them straight into the conference? A can then leave whenever.

Comment: Two different things 1) can’t get call Sid for B to modify that on a non-conference call. 2) on a conference call with A and B already in, I can’t add a fake third participant defined by some twiml. There is no 3rd person to include in the conf. It’s just another strategy to try and get B new Twiml and let A go on to making new outbound calls without dropping B.

Comment: Ah, ok. You’re only trying to send new TwiML to B. Have you tried listing the conference participants using the [participant resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource) and getting the Call Sid for B from that result?

Comment: I just tried this. I setup a conf call between A and B giving labels to each. I used the statusCallback to get the conf sid. Then I listed the participants of that conf and saw a different call sid for each participant. I then tried updating the twiml of the B call to gather some digits and on conf start I dropped A and B stayed on. This is klunky but I guess it works.

Comment: I would like to avoid having to create a conference call every time by default however. Is there a way to give the receiving party (B) new TwiML and let the caller (A) hang up without dropping the receiving party?  I know your other answers mentioned getting the sid of B but it's just not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think this question and the comments headed off in a roundabout way that wasn't exactly how to solve the initial problem. Here is what I think the real question is and some options for how to solve it:

### Question: In a two party call between participants A and B, where A dialled B, how do I send new TwiML to caller B to redirect them?

In this scenario I am guessing that A has placed the call to B using Twilio Client or the Twilio Voice SDK. And that you have a TwiML application that returns [TwiML to `<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial) caller B. To ensure you get the CallSid for caller B's leg you can use [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number) (or [`<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/client) or [`<Sip>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/sip)) to provide a [`statusCallback` URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-status-callback), like so:

```xml
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number statusCallback="WEBHOOK_URL">CALLER_B_NUMBER</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

In the parameters of the webhook request for the status callbac you will receive a `CallSid`, which identifies the outbound leg of the call to B, as well as a `ParentCallSid` which identifies the initial leg of the call that A is connected to.

You can then use this `CallSid` to [update the call using the Calls resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource#update-a-call-resource) and redirect caller B to new TwiML.

As a note, this will drop caller A, unless you provide further TwiML after the `<Dial>` or in the response to a webhook to the [URL `action` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#action). For example:

```xml
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number statusCallback="WEBHOOK_URL">CALLER_B_NUMBER</Number>
  </Dial>
  <Say>Caller B either hung up or you successfully transferred them away.</Say>
</Response>
```

Or

```xml
<Response>
  <Dial action="/after-outbound-dial">
    <Number statusCallback="WEBHOOK_URL">CALLER_B_NUMBER</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

And then return this in `/after-outbound-dial`:

```xml
<Response>
  <Say>Caller B either hung up or you successfully transferred them away.</Say>
</Response>
```

The request to the `action` URL will include a [parameter for `DialCallStatus`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#dialcallstatus) to let you know what the outcome of the call was so that you can return different results based on whether it was answered, busy, no-answer, etc.

#### Alternatives

We discussed in the comments using a conference to perform this action. While a conference is more expensive, it can give a much better experience to the person being transferred. In the case I describe above, transferring caller B will be an abrupt change from talking to caller A to whatever TwiML is next. Using a conference call and dialling a 3rd partner, C, into the call can allow for a warm transfer where caller A can introduce C and also fill in C on what is happening with caller B before dropping.

This does only apply in the case where your transfer is between people. If you need to transfer B to something automated, like a post call survey, then my answer above will suffice. It's just worth considering the conference in case there are warm transfer scenarios you want to explore in the future.

Comment: I will try the status callback and let you know. Why would the status callback offer the call sid for B but the call list plus filter API would not?

Comment: Depends on how you were filtering the call list. Can you share the code you were using or describe how you were doing that?

Comment: Tried it both with no filter and with a filter and there was no child leg sid. I don't know if it is some edge case, but we are also using a caller id on the dial. Anyway, just `client.calls.list({status: 'in-progress', to: target_number})`

Comment: When we’re you making that request? It may have been before the call was established, perhaps? Have the webhooks worked for you?

Comment: No, after establishment. The direct call with status callback on Number doesn't work. The `answered` event generates no callback. The other events (e.g. `initiated`, `completed`) do not have a `ParentCallSid` field in the webhook request body. `<Response><Dial callerId="A"><Number statusCallbackEvent="initiated ringing answered completed" statusCallback="https://foo.ngrok.io/events">B</Number></Dial></Response>`

Comment: yields webook body of `{ApiVersion: '2008-08-01', Called: B, CallStatus: 'initiated', CallGuid: 'CA48490e9865372a7b8095a8f51984e387', Timestamp: 'Mon, 28 Jun 2021 14:36:13 +0000', AccountSid: 'XYZ', CallbackSource: 'call-progress-events',   AccountGuid: 'XYZ', Caller: A, CallSegmentGuid: 'CS031bc9396f8668fb24afc83a9020faf6', SequenceNumber: '0', CallSid: 'CA48490e9865372a7b8095a8f51984e387', To: B}`

Comment: The `ApiVersion` seems odd and doesn't match https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api#base-url -- what's up with that?

Comment: That’s a good question. How are you placing this call in the first place? What is the code you are using?

Comment: twilio client 1.13.1 .. browser calls to node.js backend to get a token to which I ask for a voice grant. The browser makes call by creating Twilio.Device with the token. On device ready I connect to B. The twilio app's request url hits the backend with call info. I check for or provision a number local to the callee (same area code). I respond with the above twiml.

Comment: Your number could be set to the 2008 API (but it really shouldn’t be!). Check this doc for [how to opt in to the 2010 version API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/upgrade-from-2008-to-2010-api?code-sample=code-update-the-api-version-of-a-phone-number&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x#opt-into-api-version-2010-04-01) and let me know if that helps.

Comment: I updated the number and still saw the 2008 API. I released the number and added apiVersion to the create call and still get 2008 API. According to the docs that's for inbound calls though...

Comment: I noticed in the console `"Attribute 'statusCallbackEvent' is not allowed to appear in  element 'Number'."`yet that's in the docs so I assume somehow I'm stuck on some old api version ... I don't see how to get into the latest.

Comment: @BrianH it sounds like your account is stuck on the 2008 API for some reason. The best thing to do at this point is to reach out to the [Twilio Support team](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and get them to check over your account and sort it out.

Comment: The problem was that our account was stuck in 2008 API version.

Comment: Glad you got that sorted!

Answer (score 0):

in callback from

```js
await twilioClient.calls.create({
    statusCallback,
    statusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
    statusCallbackEvent: CALL_STATUS_EVENTS,
    machineDetection: 'Enable',
    // machineDetection: 'DetectMessageEnd',
    asyncAmd: 'true',
    asyncAmdStatusCallback,
    asyncAmdStatusCallbackMethod: 'POST',
    url,
    to,
    from,
  });
```

do update

```js
client.calls(event.CallSid ?? '')
      .update({ twiml: `<Response><Dial><Number>${process.env.AGENT1_PHONE_NUMBER}</Number></Dial></Response>` })
      .then(call => {
        console.log('==== update', call.to);
      });
```

or use FLEX

```js
client.taskrouter.v1.workspaces(workspaceSid)
    .tasks
    .create({
      attributes: JSON.stringify({
        selected_language: 'en',
        direction: 'inbound',
        from: event.Called,
        called: event.Called || 'Unknown', // Include the called number
      }),
      workflowSid: workflowSid,
    })
    .then(task => {
      console.log('Task SID:', task.sid);

      // Update the ongoing call to connect with Flex
      client.calls(ongoingCallSid)
        .update({
          twiml: `<Response><Enqueue workflowSid="${workflowSid}"></Enqueue></Response>`,
        })
        .then(updatedCall => {
          console.log('Ongoing Call updated:', updatedCall.sid);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error updating ongoing call:', error);
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error creating TaskRouter task:', error);
    });
```